# Get future timestamp of date and month without knowing the year

Tags: php

I have a date string that contains the month and the day: "January 20"

I need to convert this to a timestamp in PHP and can use strtotime to do so. The catch is I always want to return a future timestamp. So if it's December 30, 2020 today, and I have the string "January 20," I want to return the timestamp for January 20, 2021 -- not January 20, 2020.

I've come up with a few convoluted ways of doing this, such as converting to a timestamp then making sure the timestamp is > the current time. If it's not, add a year and re-convert to a timestamp. But it seems like there may be a best practice and simple way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Why do think that is not the best way to do that? Sounds like the best way to me

Comment: If you're hoping that there's a relative date format like `next January 20` that DateTime can handle, there isn't. It's annoying, but it's [not something that the parser understands](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like "next January 20." I'll go with comparing the timestamps and adjusting from there, just thought there may be a cleaner way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to compare current timestamp against this year timestamp. It should work.

```
$str = 'January 20';
$now = time();
$thisYear = strtotime($str);
$nextYear = strtotime($str . ' + 1 year');

$futureDate = $thisYear < $now ? $nextYear : $thisYear;
// 2021-01-20 - for January 20
// 2022-01-01 - for January 01
```